# CSS-Added Content Font Size Displaying Differently Between Browser and Mobile Viewing

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm using CSS to add the text 'Posted on' before the date for a blog post. This is displaying correctly within desktop browsers:

[image: Correct Display]

..But renders the actual date value and the additional 'Posted on' label with different font-sizes on mobile devices:

[image]

I am not using any responsive styles, and the entire element is specified to `font-size: 16px`, so I'm at a loss as to why the mobile display would render so differently.

**HTML Element:**

```
<p class="date">18 September, 2015</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.date {
    display:        block;
    margin-top:     0;
    margin-left:    10px;
    text-align:     left;
    font-size:      16px;
    opacity:        0.5;
}

.date:before {
    content: 'Posted on ';
}
```

Many thanks for any replies.

Comment: add font size to .date:before

Comment: @DestinationDesigns if only it was that obvious! No change..